# jQuery date picker with additional options

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am looking for a jQuery plugin (if one exists) that allows more customization to picking dates.

For example, I need the ability to choose a quarter (ex Q2 2015) or a specific Month (ex March 2015) or a specific Half (ex Half 2 2015) or a specific date all together (Jan 22, 2015).

Anyone know if this type of plugin exists already or the best way to complete to this in Javascript.

Prior to the tool I am building they were just inputting a value into Excel (ie. October 2015). Easy enough when you are typing that but when we need to create a UI experience for these different options, I am a little stuck on thinking of a way that makes the most sense.

Thanks